# Change default folder of Google Drive to drive root? (D:)

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I change the default location of the folder of Google Drive to the drive root? In this case, D:?

Where in the regedit, or which config file this info is saved?

Comment: http://gappstips.com/docs-tips/view/106/change-the-google-drive-default-folder

Comment: There are 6 answers below, but all of them are actually one of two different solutions. 1. redownload everything (works but a pain if you have >50GB on Google Drive as I do); 2. move the files, but this doesn't work for a lot of people (including me). In the end it appears there's no solution that just lets you locally move the folder location and not cause Google to redownload everything.

Comment: Exactly my problem! I want to relocate everything to the ROOT `D:\ ...` unfortunately none of the answers provided below have taken into account this single important element in your question. As well as your question about where the path is saved. Good question... I have managed (of course) to move everything to `D:\Google Drive` or `D:\CLOUD` etc but not to `D:\...` and that is what you want. I have found this just now I thought you might be interested to try this: http://rainabba.blogspot.nl/2013/07/how-to-really-move-your-google-drive.html

Answer (score 5):

This is wat I found somewhere.

Sign out from the account, and the next time you sign in, on page 2 there will be advanced setup which lets you change the location.

The exact thin with details is given here.

http://gappstips.com/docs-tips/view/106/change-the-google-drive-default-folder

Comment: This forces you to re-download everything. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: This method probably doesn't work anymore. Leaving the answer for reference.

Edit: Use with caution, doesn't work for some...

Following procedure doesn't require you to delete and redownload the Google Drive folder. As found [in this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/2BTBo8G3res):

1. Quit Drive by selecting its icon in the menubar (taskbar on PC) and
   clicking 'Quit.'
2. Move the Google Drive folder to the desired location.
3. When you open Drive again, an error message will be in the Drive icon menu saying that it cannot find the Google Drive folder. Click on that message.
4. Click 'Locate folder' in the window that pops up, navigate to the location you moved it to, and click 'Reconnect.'

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit The Google Drive program
2. Rename the google drive folder to something else
3. Restart and Relogin into the Google Drive program
4. You will get an error message saying that the google drive folder couldnt be located and be able to choose a new location, make a new folder, name it "google drive".

The drive data will now be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

By sheer dumb luck - just before quitting - I found a solution! I had just disconnected and logged out for the tenth time.   Renaming had not worked, it wouldn't accept the new folder. This time I had just not deleted, renamed or moved the prior incarnation of the Google Drive folder in the location Drive automatically places it.  So after re-installing (double-clicking downloaded Drive app icon) and logging on to Drive this time I got a message as it attempted to re-download that the Google Drive folder was not empty.  It now prompted me to locate a new, empty folder!  I was able to go to my other hard drive - this one is a second internal hard drive, but it probably would have let me choose any location - and did not complain as long as I gave it an empty folder.  Incidentally the folder I chose was not named Google Drive, as that was my preference.  I am on Mac Snow Leopard, 10.6.8.  This was a Google Drive version downloaded August 2014.  (I need to stay on this OS for now, but it's not supported by the most recent version of Drive or by any of the main free cloud systems I've checked.)