# How to change the download location of files from google drive API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've downloaded files from google drive through the API.
My only problem is that I can't find anywhere how to change the target location of the files. It's all downloading to the DEBUG folder.

Here is the code:

```
var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Utilities.Log("Starting download..");
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
            (download_stat) => {
                switch (download_stat.Status) {
                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading: {
                            Console.WriteLine(download_stat.BytesDownloaded);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Completed: {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Failed: {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                            break;
                        }
                }
            };

        request.Download(stream);
```

thx

Comment: [This](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/drive/change-the-google-drive-default-folder/) could help you to change the default download location. It contains the step by step process on how to achieve the function you are looking for, the drawback is it will force you to re-download everything. You can refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027524/change-default-folder-of-google-drive-to-drive-root-d) for more details.

Comment: Thx
I contact google support and they said this option not exist ?!
it's unbelievable such a big company get to the market product with no minimal features.